# Use of 'self' only as a parameter in a method?

Tags: python, class

I created this class earlier.

```
class Dog():
    """A simple attempt to model a dog."""

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """Initialise name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """Simulate a dog sitting in response to a command."""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")
```

Now, the book I am reading says the following

> Because these methods don’t need additional information like a name or age, we just define them to have one parameter, self.

I'm confused by what this means.

Does this mean that when we pass the parameter `self`, the method has automatic access to the attributes `self.name` and `self.age`?

The book in question is *Python Crash Course* by Eric Mattes.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: You have access to the attributes of any parameters you receive. In this case, the only one you care about is `self`.

Comment: @azalea I don't think this is a duplicate as that post also makes reference to ruby but I am discussing the subject in a different context.

Comment: In a nutshell, with `d = Dog("bob", 10)`, `d.sit()` is equivalent to `Dog.sit(d)`.

Comment: @Barmar what does the line `Because these methods don’t need additional information like a name or age` mean though, because that's the bit that seems to be confusing me!

Comment: I think that's just drawing a contrast to the `__init__` method which takes two additional arguments. The `sit` method doesn't need additional arguments because the `name` attribute has already been set on `self`.

Comment: It means exactly what you have understood. The author of the book seems to be not very clear: _"Because these methods **don’t need additional information like a name**..."_ `sit(self)` **is** accessing `name`: `self.name.title()`. However, `sit()` can get this info from self because it was stored as an attribute.